# jplayer video not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jplayer

I am getting an error when trying to view videos in jplayer on IE9. 
The videos play fine on Chrome, FireFox, IE8 and IE10.

The error is

```
jPlayer 2.4.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!  
Media URL could not be loaded.  
Check media URL is valid.  
Context: media/commercials/kandahar_psa.m4v
```

First off, the URL it's saying is accurate. The video is available in 4 formats. mp4, m4v, ogv, webm

I'm not sure why it plays in some browsers and not others.